# is there a function to get axis interval

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a axes variable `ax`.

```
ax.get_yticks()
Out[37]: array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])
```

I want to get the ticks interval（0.2-0). Is there a function to return the result (0.2)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
intervalSize = ax.get_yticks[1] - ax.get_yticks[0]
```

Comment: @will That's correct: intervals are defined by constant steps.

Comment: They are not necessarily constant. `ax.get_yticks[1:] - ax.get_yticks[:-1]` gives you the full range of intervals, in case they are not constant.

Comment: @Bart exactly. Though - what kind of arrays is matplotlib returning? what you have there does not work for native python lists.

Comment: It's a `numpy.ndarray`: `type(pl.gca().get_xticks())` returns `numpy.ndarray`